# validate json post from external

Tags: json, codeigniter, logging

I have script to receive post json object from external system.
It supposed to receive json object with the following:

```
{"data":[{"BegRecNbr": 81, "RecFrag": [{"Fields": {"mA": [1406.205078125, 1914.948486328125], "mB": [1769.690673828125, 1816.0640869140625, 1692.6290283203125, 744.02020263671875]}, "RecNbr": 81, "TimeOfRec": [731495520, 0]}], "TableNbr": 3}, {"BegRecNbr": 82, "RecFrag": [{"Fields": {"mA": [1406.19384765625, 1915.2742919921875], "mB": [1768.99462890625, 1815.36767578125, 1692.615478515625, 744.01434326171875]}, "RecNbr": 82, "TimeOfRec": [731496480, 0]}], "TableNbr": 3, "NbrOfRecs": 1}]}
```

I can not touch external system, so I can only log to file object post, before i process.

i tried to log file using log_message in CI just for debugging

```
log_message('debug','values json1: '.$_POST);
$log_my_post = var_export($_POST, TRUE); 
$log_my_post = str_replace(array("\r","\n"," "), '', $log_my_post); 
log_message('debug','values json2: '.$log_my_post);
```

in log file, i can only see

```
DEBUG - 2013-07-22 16:01:28 --> values json1: Array
DEBUG - 2013-07-22 16:01:28 --> values json2: array()
```

How can i see detail of the array sent to my script from the external system
so that i can validate the correct message sent?

Appreciate for the help.

regards

Comment: where are u receiving json in client side or server side?

Comment: @iBlue in server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
$string='{"data":[{"BegRecNbr": 81, "RecFrag": [{"Fields": {"mA": [1406.205078125, 1914.948486328125], "mB": [1769.690673828125, 1816.0640869140625, 1692.6290283203125, 744.02020263671875]}, "RecNbr": 81, "TimeOfRec": [731495520, 0]}], "TableNbr": 3}, {"BegRecNbr": 82, "RecFrag": [{"Fields": {"mA": [1406.19384765625, 1915.2742919921875], "mB": [1768.99462890625, 1815.36767578125, 1692.615478515625, 744.01434326171875]}, "RecNbr": 82, "TimeOfRec": [731496480, 0]}], "TableNbr": 3, "NbrOfRecs": 1}]}';
print_r( json_decode($string,1));
```

Try to use json_decode($string,1). The 1 means you return an array instead of an object.

Comment: Hi @Luc when i use json_decode($string,1), it return blank in logfile and give warning "Severity: Warning --> json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given...."

Comment: Then something is wrong with your $string. If you exactly copy/paste those two lines it does not work? What PHP version are you using? The error is weird, parameter 1 is $string, which is a string in my example. But according to your error, it is an array...

Comment: Hi @Luc, Like in my top sentences, I supposed to receive json obj from external system, and i would like to validate by storing in file. But i still can not get detail json in the file

Comment: i solve the problem by using file_get_contents("php://input"); thanks anyway for all response

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
log_message('debug','values json2: '.json_encode($log_my_post));
```

Comment: hi @iBlue, the result of json_encode($_POST) is still only Array. For the second one  .json_encode($log_my_post)), i let you know in a few minutes